# Is there a nice packaging tool for configuration packages?

Tags: configuration, packaging

I use packages to configure my system. Each package depends on the application packages that it configures, and contains the configuration files. (The repository lives at https://github.com/majewsky/system-configuration.)

My impression is that building configuration packages using the native packaging tools (in my case PKGBUILD files, since I'm on Arch Linux) is unnecessarily cumbersome. To package a configuration file with a single line of content, I have to put the file in my repository, reference the file in the PKGBUILD's `sources`, and install the file in the PKGBUILD's `install()` routine. (This is not specific to Arch Linux, I just used it as an example since that's what I use ATM.)

Are there options for streamlining this process? Something like a package description format targeted at configuration packages, where you have a single description file containing all the dependencies and configuration files, which can be processed into a configuration package with a single command.

[EDIT: To clarify, I'm *not* looking for any of the classic configuration management tools, like Puppet/Chef/Ansible/Salt/cfEngine. I consider every one of these too fat and built my own, Holo (http://holocm.org) which extends arbitrary system package managers to also handle configuration. The only thing that I find lacking in this approach is that it is relatively tedious to set up a build process for system packages that only contain a handful static files.]

If the answer is no, I'll build it myself, but I figure some investigation into prior art is useful. My googling didn't turn up anything useful so far.

Comment: *"Are there options for streamlining this process?"* -> From the sound of things I'm guessing it might start `#!/bin/sh` and be over within a dozen lines.  You don't really expect someone to release that as a tool, do you?

Comment: I sketched it out in my head, and can't see that fitting within a dozen lines of shell script.

Comment: have you looked into chef or puppet? They might help you accomplish what you need.

Comment: I use Chef at work, and that convinced me never to let this horrible bloated mess near my private systems.

Comment: Fair enough.  Personally I'd use perl and not be so concerned about LOC since it still seems like it can't take more than an hour to code -- but that's me.  Anyway, in adding the `arch-linux` tag above (since different *linux* distros use different package management systems, this is not really a generic/global *nix question), I noticed a tag for [makepkg](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Makepkg) -- dunno if that is good enough, but if not you might want to add, "Yes I know about `makepkg` but this soup is too hot!"

Comment: What about Ansible then?

Comment: Edited the question to clarify that I'm not looking for a configuration management tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of not leaving unanswered questions lying around, I shall note that I wrote https://github.com/holocm/holo-build and https://github.com/majewsky/art which together make for a nice package building workflow.